# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int' :Why i can not subtract two functions directly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the difference of the outputs of two functions.
I studied java before.In java ,to use one function subtract another function directly is possible.
Can someone tell me why i can not do the same in python?Is is simply becuz python can not do that or becuz I can not substract a tuple with int type?

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import time


@jit
def foo(x: int, y: int) ->float:
    tt = time.time()
    s = 0
    for i in range(x,y):
           s += i
    print("Time used: {} sec".format(time.time() - tt))
    return s


print("value of foo", foo(1, 1000))


def foo2(x, y)->float:
    tt = time.time()
    s = 0
    for i in range(x, y):
       s += i
    print("Time used for foo2: {} sec".format(time.time() - tt))
    return s


print("value of foo2", foo2(1, 1000))

a= foo(1, 1000)
b= foo2(1, 1000)
print (a-b)
print(type(a))
print(type(b))
print(type(foo2((1, 1000)-foo(1, 1000))))
```

Excepted:to get a float number of the difference of the ouputs of two different functions

Actual:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Time used: 0.03690075874328613 sec
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled1\numbaTester.py", 
line 35, in <module>
value of foo 499500
print(type(foo2((1, 1000)-foo(1, 1000))))
Time used for foo2: 0.0 sec
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
value of foo2 499500
Time used: 0.0 sec
Time used for foo2: 0.0 sec
0
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
Time used: 0.0 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect, you have an extra parenthesis in your last print statement.

If you change it to `print(foo2(1, 1000) - foo(1, 1000))`, you will see that you can subtract these functions (or you could change it to `print(type(foo2(1, 1000) - foo(1, 1000)))` if you just want to see the output type rather than the result similar to your initial attempt).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly.I tried your first suggestion to delete the type() ,but i still can not subtract them.                            
Console still display:  print(foo2((1, 1000)-foo(1, 1000)))

     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Comment: @Archo - you still have an extra parenthesis in there. Copy and paste the following and it should work: `print(foo2(1, 1000) - foo(1, 1000))`